# Combine Two Tables and If the address of a personId is not present in the Address table, report null instead

Tags: mysql

Write an SQL query to report the first name, last name, city, and state of each person in the Person table. If the address of a personId is not present in the Address table, report null instead.

Comment: You want to learn `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.